# Identifying RA and Dec duplicates in a table

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, astropy, astronomy

I am trying to create a table that consists of objects in a particular region. I am putting together irac, 2mass, and wise data. I have combined all of the data into one table, and am now trying to eliminate duplicates based on RA and Dec coordinates. My end goal is to have a complete table without any duplicates. So if an object is in the irac data, there isn't an equivalent from the 2mass or wise data. I am new to using python. It would be nice to get the row # of the duplicates.

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('filename.csv')

duplicate = []

for num in df['ra' and 'dec']:
     if any(df['ra' and 'dec'].duplicated()):
          dublicate.append(num)
```

This has been running for a while, I just not sure if it is correct or working efficiently. The ra and dec values are in two separate columns.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The task you are trying to do is catalog cross-matching of sky coordinates.  The pandas methods methods like `drop_duplicates` are not appropriate because they use exact numerical comparisons, but in general the RA and Dec values in catalogs will be different by values related to the catalog accuracies.

Efficient catalog cross-matching is a big subject by itself, but you can get started with these references:

- http://learn.astropy.org/Coordinates.html#Using-coordinates-and-table-to-match-and-compare-catalogs
- https://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/coordinates/matchsep.html#matching-catalogs

Answer (score -2):

I would have done it like this. Not sure about time taken though. You can give a try and let us know.

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('filename.csv')
New_DF = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['ra','dec'])
```

Documentation is here (https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html)

Comment: This answer isn't going to be successful on data from across astronomical catalogs. 
 It is an attempt to answer a question without considering issues that the questioner raised at all and without respect to the astronomy and astropy specific aspects of this question.